# Getting a single value from database - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get first name and last name of registered users.
This is my getfirstname , getlastname function in the model

```
public function getf()
{  

  $email = $this->input->post('email');
  $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
  $query = $this->db->get('users');
        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
          $row = $query->row();
          echo $row->fname;
        }

}


public function getl()
{
    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        echo $row->lname;
    }

}
```

In My Contoller:

```
public function members()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {

        $data['fname'] = $this->getf(); 
        $data['lname'] = $this->getl();
        $this->load->view('members', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('main/restricted');
    }
}
```

Im echoing the fname and lname variables in my view which prints 'Array' and not actual firstname and lastname

```
echo $fname;
echo $lname;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to model is totally wrong and you are not
following the standard procedure. Try it like this.
Seperate the logics

Controller

```
public function members()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {

        $email  =   $this->input->post('email');
        $result =   $this->mymodel->getnames($email); 
        if($result){
            $data['fname'] = $result->first_name;
            $data['lname'] = $result->last_name;
            $this->load->view('members', $data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('main/restricted');
    }
}
```

And create single function for model not two functions
for two values that could be retrieved with single function
Also return the object instead of echoing

```
public function getnames($email)
{  
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you haven't actually declared the 'fname' and 'lname' variables, unless I've missed it, but if it keeps returning 'Array' then it is because you need to serialise the array with

```
$variable = json_encode($arrayName);
```

This will turn the array into a string, hope this helps.

Comment: But i'm passing the $data array into the view. fname and lname would be converted into variables in the view right?

Comment: Ah I see but you can't directly turn an array to a standalone string variable... you have to stringify or serialise the array so that it can be broken apart, or if not then it is because you're not specifying which part of the array you want to use... so if I had an array like... fname <= Dan lname <= Morgan i would have to do $variable[0] to print Dan and $variable[1] to print Morgan but as you have two separate arrays try this... echo $fname[0]; echo $lname[0];

Comment: $fname[0] is empty i guess. Its not printing anything. var_dump reveals that it is set to NULL. Unable to find why getf and getl functions are not returning values

Comment: I think it could be because you've created the Query and you've created the Row... you have created the Result, in MySQL you have to create the query, pass the query to a result and pass the result to the row

Answer (score 0):

UserModel

```
class UserModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function getItemByEmail($email)
    {  
        // check email
        $this->load->helper('email');

        if( ! $email OR ! valid_email($email))
            return array();

        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $item = $this->db->get('users')->row();

        return $item;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function members()
{
    if( ! $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
        redirect('main/restricted');

    $this->load->model('UserModel');

    $this->load->view('members', array(
        'userRow' => $this->UserModel->getItemByEmail($this->input->post('email', TRUE))
    ));
}
```

View:

```
<?= (isset($userRow->fname) ? $userRow->fname : ''); ?>
```